# Issue with CSS Text box rendering in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have been trying to build a search engine using basic HTML and CSS for my Uni but IE just doesnt seem to like text boxes. Works perfectly fine in Chrome and Edge but for some reason doesnt work well in IE.

Screenshots attached below.
[Image in IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7KnV.png)
[Image in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qrqbc.png)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Code for the search box and the search text button:

```css
.search-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 260px;
    left: 46%;

    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: #2f3640;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.search-box:hover > .search-text {
    width: 350px;
    padding: 0 6px;

}

.search-box:hover > .search-btn {
    background: white;

}

.search-btn {
    color: #e84118;
    float: right;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #2f3640;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 1s;

}

.search-text {
    font-family: VFRegular;
    border: 1px red solid;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 0px;


}

/*
.search-box:hover ~ .category-box {
    width: 400px;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;


}


.category-box:hover {
    width: 400px;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.category-box {
    position: absolute;
    align-items: center;
    top: 38%;
    left: 50%;
    text-decoration-color: white;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: #2f3640;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 0px;
    color: white;
    visibility: collapse;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: width 1s, height 1s, transform 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;

}
*/

.search-box > ul {
    left: -100px;
    background-color: #2f3640;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 15px;


}

.search-box > ul li {
    left: -10px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    z-index: 1;
}

.search-box > ul li:last-child {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.search-box > ul li:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="entire-searchbox">
    <div class="search-box">
        <input class="search-text" type="text" placeholder="Type to search">

        <a class="search-btn" href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        </a>

        <ul id="testListDummy">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you set 400px in .search-box class should be work

Comment: what should i set 400 px too?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the height property for the .search-text, code as below:

```
    .search-text {
        font-family: VFRegular;
        border: 1px red solid;
        background: none;
        outline: none;
        float: left;
        padding: 0;
        color: white;
        font-size: 16px;
        -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: 0.5s;
        transition: 0.5s;
        line-height: 40px;
        width: 0px;
        height:58px;
    }
```

The output as below:

[image]

Comment: worked but now i have another issue (Chrome - https://imgur.com/ItzxBvT) (IE - https://imgur.com/67aphSL). My content is out of alignment

Comment: Great, first, I suggest you could mark this answer as an accepted answer, since this question is solved, then, you could create a new thread about the new issue, when you post the new question, it is better to post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it might be easier for community members reproduce the problem and help you solve the problem. Thanks for your understanding.